# How do I stop a loading indicator when In-App-Purchase window pops up on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

When user tap the purchase a product button, i wanna show loading indicator before

In-App-Purchase window pops up.

But i don't know which delegate method i stop the indicator.

Comment: are you using UIAactivityIndicatorView for this....?

Comment: Yes I'm using UIAactivityIndicatorView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could possible show it when you add the payment to SKPaymentque

```
    SKPayment *newPayment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:aPakage.storeProduct];
   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:newPayment];
```

For removing you could implement a method for

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {

[transactionsArray addObjectsFromArray:transactions];
for (SKPaymentTransaction *currentTransaction in transactions) {
    switch (currentTransaction.transactionState) {
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing: {
            break;
        }
        case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased: {
            [self completeTransaction:currentTransaction];
            break;
        }
        case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed: {
            [self failedTransaction:currentTransaction];
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

}

you can remove your loading screen when this delegate method is called according to state of the purchase.Me personally implemented two separate functions for failed and succeeded transactions.

Comment: thank you for your answer but can i ask one more question ?       what should i do to know when the purchase alert window pops up ? i want to stop loading indicator when it pops